# Java tar.gz compression - permissions issue

Tags: java, apache-commons

I'm having an issue with Java.  I was wondering using the Apache Commons Compress (or if there is a better way), is there a way to edit a file without decompressing the tar.gz.  What I am running into, is the tar.gz directory and files have root ownership and group status as well as specific rwxrwxrwx permissions that get erased when I uncompress and recompress.  The file is a unix file while I am running the program on a Windows machine.

I am trying to find a way to uncompress in java without losing those permissions that were originally there, or edit the files within.  Any help in the right direction would be appreciated as I am at a slight lose on how to do it with Java.

Any help would be appreciated!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Permissions are OS specific. However, you can try the java.io.File class that allows you to set permissions: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html

The idea is store the permission somewhere, extract the file, do whatever, compress again and apply the permissions.

Comment: Yea I just realized I was using setMode incorrectly which was part of my problem.  Is there a way to reapply the User and Group in the tar.gz?  As I believe the tar.gz requires root access when it ends up getting uploaded.  So far I have tried setUserId(0) which I believe is root and getuserId(0) on each file but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Yes, take a look at TarArchiveEntry. You can setUser and setGroup there: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/apidocs/org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/tar/TarArchiveEntry.html

Comment: Thanks Alexandre that did it... I am using TarArchiveEntry.  For some reason I wasn't using the right method for it though to set the group and user.  I was doing it by ID which since I am going from Linux to Windows it probably didn't like.  Still didn't solve my problem but I'll keep looking.

I basically am trying to un-tar.gz a configuration file and re-tar.gz it so a piece of equipment will accept it and I am getting "invalid config" error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking specifically for tar.gz and not only zip, then you can use

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/

You can set up individual flags using this: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/javadocs/api-1.8.1/index.html